# Highchart series did not draw

Tags: highcharts

i create an empty highchart and add a series to the chart.

This is my code:

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'hccontainer',
                    zoomType: 'x'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Telegramme'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Offline'
                },
                exporting: {
                         enabled: false
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: true
                },

                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    tickPixelInterval: 150,
                    maxZoom: 20 * 1000
                },
                yAxis: {
                    minPadding: 0.2,
                    maxPadding: 0.2,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Value',
                        margin: 80
                    }
                }
            });
```

And here for example i add a series:

```
$.ajax({
                        'url' : 'ajax.php',
                        'type': 'GET',
                        'data': {
                                'action' : 'eibmon_hctel',
                                'hsid': hsid,
                                'grp': grp,
                                'df': datefrom,
                                'dt': dateto
                        },
                        success: function(items) {
                            chart.addSeries({                        
                                name: series_name,
                                data: items
                            }, true);

                        },
                        cache: false
                    });
```

The ajax.php send this result:

> {"1441614256000":"1","1441586308000":"0","1441523112000":"1","1441515496000":"0","1441360423000":"1"
>   ,"1441344522000":"1","1441341118000":"0","1441254853000":"1","1441238297000":"0","1441094577000":"1"
>   ,"1441086395000":"0","1441086143000":"1","1441085875000":"0","1441085622000":"1"}

The chart will be redrawn but the line is missing. In the legend the new series get displayed. Is it not possible to start with an empty chart?

Thanks

Comment: Any errors in console? What is `series_name` and `items` format? I don't see you setting those in your ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your JSON structure is icorrect. You should have a x/y fields and number values.

Example:

```
{
  x:"1441614256000",
  y:"1"
}
```

After loading data, you can convert your json into correct form, parsing data in preprocessing.